# How to save a List View in a file and load it later? UWP C#

Tags: c#, file, listview, uwp, settings

I have a ListView in a UWP application with many ListViews as its ListViewItems. The ListViews inside the main ListView are lists of custom ListViewItems (with a grid with elements as their content).

The user can always add or remove either the custom ListViewItems in the ListViews in the main ListView or the entire ListViews in the main ListView.

**I wanted to save all the changes made by user in application's settings or in a file** (to save the created ListViews and custom ListViewItems and load them on start)

**Is there a way to do that?**

**What I've tried:**

- JSON convert (`JsonConvert.serializeObject()`) resulted in a Stack Overflow exception
- BinaryFormatter resulted in an exception saying that the ListView is not serializable

**Please provide the code showing how to save and load the ListView**

**The application structure looks like this:**

Main ListView (that should be saved) > Main ListView items (ListViews) (can be added/removed by user) > Custom ListViewItems (not only strings) (can be added/removed by user)

Comment: Normally, you would not save the ListViewItems (which are UI elements), but the data from which these are created (i.e. the model).

Comment: The added ListViewItems (ListViews) are custom, their ListViewItems can be added or removed. I need something to save either the Main List View, List of ListViewItems (ListViews) (`List<ListView>`) or maybe a collection of ListViews, if any of these things are possible to save anywhere (settings or a file or other way).

Comment: Why not  serialize itemsource  to json and  save it  to file ?

Comment: You mean the `mainListView.ItemsSource` which are many ListViews? If it's possible, can you share a link to how it's done? I've tried serializing the main list view to json and it resulted in a Stack Overflow exception, I don't know what will be with ItemsSource.

Comment: I mean you need design your listview with datasource and store the datasource  to the file. And as  Klaus Gütter  said, ListViewItems does not support to serialize.

Comment: And how to do that? What can be the datasource in this case?

Comment: I have make sample below, please check it, and if the answer is helpful please consider mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you need design nesting listview with datasource and store the datasource to the file. And as Klaus Gütter said, ListViewItems does not support to serialize.

For example

**Xaml code**

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="SaveList" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ListContent>> Items { set; get; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
     
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

        if (value == null)
        {
            var list1 = new ObservableCollection<ListContent>() { new ListContent { Content = "1" }, new ListContent { Content = "2" }, new ListContent { Content = "3" } };
            var list2 = new ObservableCollection<ListContent>() { new ListContent { Content = "A" }, new ListContent { Content = "B" }, new ListContent { Content = "C" } };
            var list3 = new ObservableCollection<ListContent>() { new ListContent { Content = "一" }, new ListContent { Content = "二" }, new ListContent { Content = "三" } };
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ListContent>>() { list1, list2, list3 };
        }
        else
        {
            Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ListContent>>>(value.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Items);
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        // Create a simple setting.
        localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = json;

        // Read data from a simple setting.
      
    }
}
public class ListContent
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And how to create the ListContent if it's not only a TextBlock? In this case a grid is created `Grid tileGrid = new Grid();` then an image and a TextBlock, which are added to the grid `tileGrid.Children.Add(tileImage); tileGrid.Children.Add(tileText);` and then it's set as the item's content `ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem() { Content = tileGrid, };`

Comment: you could edit the xaml code base on your design