# Is there a feature to shift item on top in a listview

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a ListView which ItemSource is bind to an ObservableCollection. This collection stores a list of some user's chat messages. Now I want to shift that item on top whenever that user receives a new chat message. Likewise in WhatsApp and slack app. So I want to know what is the correct way of doing this. Right now I am removing an item from the list and then adding it to the 0th index but this way sometimes I am getting parameter incorrect issues. So is there any way so that I can directly shift any chat to the top without removing it.

Xaml code for listview is below:

```
<ListView MaxHeight="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenedChatMaxHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Margin="0,10,0,0"
                          CanDragItems="True"
                          Loaded="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenedChatDataLoaded}"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"                                  
                          SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenChatListSeletedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenChatList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.ChatSelected}"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenPinnedChatListItemClick}">
                          <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: i think you can specify some property(e.g. recieveddatetime), and use `collectionviewsource` to automatically sort the items in ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the Move method but in that case, I always get index out of range error my view just gets out of focus.

[`Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.move?view=net-5.0) method will moves the item at the **specified index** to a new location in the collection. Please add debug point to check if the `oldIndex` is correct. Above problem looks you have not get correct oldindex.

> Is there a feature to shift item on top in a listview

For fixing the chart item in the top, we often make a separate top list. When you want to fix the chart item, you could remove it from the previous chart list, and add it into top list.

For this way, it is easy to make a istop style, but not make datatemplete selector for previous list. And you could also store the istop chart items in local storage to improve rendering performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any examples of how to store the istop chart items?

Comment: Please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65493776/7254781)

Answer (score 1):

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class has a [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.move?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) method that you can use to move an item from one index to another:

```
OpenedChatMaxHeight.Move(oldIndex, 0);
```

This is more convenient than manually removing and adding the item back at index 0.

Comment: And emits the appropriate message so the ListView can properly reuse the view, so you could conceivably do animations and such with no issue.

Comment: What do you mean by emits the appropriate message? can you please elobrate?

Comment: I have tried the Move method but in that case, I always get index out of range error my view just gets out of focus. I have to manage  ListView explicitly. So I am looking for an alternative way  to do this